# How do I take all of the text from a file and insert it into one row's column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, text-files, bulkinsert

I want to read all of the text in a file and insert it into a table's column.  One suggested way was to use `BULK INSERT`.  Because of the syntax, I thought it would be better to `BULK INSERT` into a temp table, then eventually, I would `SELECT` from the temp table along with other values to fill the main table's row.

I tried:

```
USE [DB]
CREATE TABLE #ImportText
(
    [XSLT] NVARCHAR(MAX)
)

BULK INSERT #ImportText
FROM 'C:\Users\me\Desktop\Test.txt'

SELECT * FROM #ImportText

DROP TABLE #ImportText
```

But, it is creating a new row in #ImportText per newline in the file.  I don't want it split at all.  I could not find a `FIELDTERMINATOR` that would allow for this. (i.e. end of file character)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
BULK INSERT #ImportText
FROM 'C:\Users\me\Desktop\Test.txt'
WITH (ROWTERMINATOR = '\0')
```

Comment: Yeah, that works, thanks.  I guess I just over-looked ROWTERMINATOR in the documentation.  Another possibility I ran into while waiting for an answer, is to use OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Users\me\Desktop\Test.txt',SINGLE_NCLOB).